# Need to find users flow based on keywords for my website

Tags: seo, google-analytics, web-development, keywords

I am new to SEO, I have a website, I want to find out the keywords that user searched and reached into my website. How can I find out them? is there any existing tools for that?
currently having analytics for that site

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Search Console (former Webmaster tools) to analyze the keywords users used to reach your site:

> Group results by query strings that users searched for on Google. Only
>   searches that returned your site will be included. Very rare queries
>   are not shown in these results to protect the privacy of the user
>   making the query.

Have a look at: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics

Comment: tried search console also but on that no result found about the keyword

Comment: Are you sure it is working? Works for me.

Comment: okay then I think the visitor came from any other sources like facebook or something no one through keyword, 
Thanks for your support

Comment: Sure, it can happen, you should look for **organic search** that is the visitors who came from searching with keywords, but your visitors can be arriving from social networks, other referrers or directly to your site. cheers